# Electron density question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, density, identical-particles

On wikipedia it says that:

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})= \sum_{{s}_{1}} \cdots \sum_{{s}_{N}} \int \ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_1 \ \cdots \int\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_N  \ \left( \sum_{i=1}^N \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_i)\right)|\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,s_{1},\mathbf{r}_{2},s_{2},...,\mathbf{r}_{N},s_{N})|^2 \tag{1}$$

Let's say $N=3$ and spin summations are implicit.

then
$$\rho(\mathbf{r})= \int d\mathbf{r}_1  \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3 \left[\delta( \mathbf{r}- \mathbf{r}_1)+ \delta( \mathbf{r}- \mathbf{r}_2) + \delta( \mathbf{r}- \mathbf{r}_3)\right] |\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2 \tag{2} $$

We will have three terms:

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=  \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2  + \int d\mathbf{r}_1   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{1},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2 +
\  \int d\mathbf{r}_1   \int d\mathbf{r}_2  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{1},\mathbf{r}_{2})|^2 \tag{3}$$

Where I considered the anti-symmetry of the wave functions.
This is my final result, I don't see how I can simply it further.

I don't understand why (how) this will be equal to:

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=  3\int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2  \tag{4}$$

or, for the general case:

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})= N \int \ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_2 \ \cdots \int\ \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}_N  \ |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},...,\mathbf{r}_{N})|^2 \tag{5}$$

This is basically saying that all the terms in Eq. (3) are equal. Did I do something wrong?

A: Jason Funderberker's comment helped me understand what was my problem.

Comment: I've edited the equations. Feel free to undo if you want. Further, I think that you made a 'mistake' in the third term; there should be no $r_3$ but a $r_1$, no? Anyway, here is a hint: Each of the three terms only depend on $r$, whereas $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ are dummy variables since you integrate over them. Thus, label them as you want.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the mistake. And yes, your hint made it very clear.

Comment: If you know the answer to your question, you can (if you want to) also write an answer yourself. Actually, this is encouraged, cf. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). This could help potential future readers.

Comment: Thanks. I've just done it.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the hint given by @Jason Funderberker in the comments section.

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=  \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2  + \int d\mathbf{r}_1   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{1},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2 +
\  \int d\mathbf{r}_1   \int d\mathbf{r}_2  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{1},\mathbf{r}_{2})|^2 \tag{1}$$

The variables inside the integrals ($d\mathbf{r}_1,d\mathbf{r}_2 ,d\mathbf{r}_3$) are dummy variables. Therefore, it doesn't matter what number we use to label them.

This means that:
$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=  \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2  + \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2  + \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2  \tag{2}$$

Arriving the final expression:

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})= 3 \int d\mathbf{r}_2   \int d\mathbf{r}_3  |\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_{2},\mathbf{r}_{3})|^2 $$

Which agrees with the general expression in Eq. (5) on the original post.